# Bootstrap grid with one column auto width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to make a list of items, where each row has 4 columns..
I've tried to use the bs3 grid system, but it doesn't fit all my requirements (or at least I can't make it work), since one of the columns need to use all the available space..

Example:

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                             |
|                                   Container                                 |
|Checkbox| Name (130px)| Message                                        | Date|
|Checkbox| Name (130px)| Message adasdsadsadsadsadsadasaaaaaaaaaaaaa    | Date|
|Checkbox| Name (130px)| Message adsadsadsadsadsadsadsaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... | Date|
|Checkbox| Name (130px)| Message                                        | Date|
|Checkbox| Name (130px)| Message                                        | Date|
|....                                                                         |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
```

Basically, the date column should always be on the right, and the message column should use all the available width, and if the message is bigger than the available space, it should be truncated (or the overflow hidden)

Thanks

Comment: You can use an structure like 3-column 3-column 6-column and inside the last one put message and date with custom css properties to acomplish that ....

Comment: Bootstrap columns are meant for responsive grids. They are not meant to be used like tables. What you are looking for is a `display: table-cell;` scenario. Just wrap your `div` in one `col-xs-12` column.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Bootstraps grid is primarily *layouting* purposes, what you have here is grid based *content*, aka, a table.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td:first-of-type,
td:last-of-type {
  width: 50px;
}
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>fit</td>
    <td>stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch
      stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch</td>
    <td>fit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fit</td>
    <td>stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch
      stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch</td>
    <td>fit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fit</td>
    <td>stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch
      stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch stretch</td>
    <td>fit</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `div`s in one large column and then set `display: table-cell` on those:

Something like the snippet below.

***Fiddle***: *http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/qan2khse/*

***Snippet***:

```css
div.table {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
}
div.cell {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
}
div.cell:first-child, div.cell:nth-child(2)  {
    width: 10%;
}
div.cell:nth-child(3) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.cell:last-child {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <span>Caption</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 table">
            <div class="cell">one</div>
            <div class="cell">two</div>
            <div class="cell">three</div>
            <div class="cell">four</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```